# A question of newtonian mechanics from Kleppner and Kolenkow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> **Bead on rod**
>
> A small bead of mass **m** is free to slide on a thin rod.
>   The rod rotates in a plane about one end at constant angular
>   velocity **ω**. Show that the motion is given by *r* = A($1$/$e{^γ}^t$)
>   + B${e^γ}^t$ ,
>   where **γ** is a constant which you must find and **A** and **B** are arbitrary
>   constants. Neglect gravity.
>
> Show that for a particular choice of initial conditions [that is,
>   r(t = 0) and v(t = 0)] it is possible to obtain a solution such
>   that **r** decreases continually in time, but that for any other choice
>   r will eventually increase. (Exclude cases where the bead hits the
>   origin.)

In my attempt I found that **γ**= **ω** (which was asked in the first part of the question). But I couldn't understand what I am supposed to do for the second part. Would appreciate if someone can help me out to solve the second part.

Comment: which page? which number?

Comment: Page no.113 ,question no. 3.21 (2nd edition) ; question 2.33 in the 1st edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At *t=0*, you are allowed to place the bead at any location along the rod (**r$_0$**) and you are also allowed to provide it any initial **radial** velocity (**v$_0$**).

For **r** to decrease continuously in time, ***B*** must be **zero**, otherwise **Be$^{\omega t}$** will eventually dominate ***r*** behavior.

$$
r(t)=Ae^{-\omega t}  ==> r_0=A
$$
$$
v(t)=\frac{dr}{dt}=-A\omega e^{-\omega t} ==> v_0=-A\omega
$$

So **$v_0=-r_0\omega$**, meaning you can place the bead anywhere but initially push it **inward** at exactly the prescribed velocity.

Comment: "eventually dominate r behavior"- by this did you mean that  r will increase rather than decrease? As the t value increases value of $Be^{\omega t}$ increases but this won't happen if B=0. If what I have written is what you meant I guess I understood.

Comment: Yes. For whatever A, if B is not zero, there will be a time T, when r will increase for any  t>T.